# Управляемый тип в неуправляемый тип

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Есть textBox1. Код:

```
this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(233, 20);
this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
this->textBox1->TabIndex = 4;
this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_TextChanged);
```

И есть кнопка (вот там, где типа при ее нажатии). Код:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    // тут например арифметические действия с числом textBox1->TextChanged
}
```

Как считать значение `textBox1->TextChanged` и в кнопке переделать тип этого значение в int?

Comment: @Анатолий Козлов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textBox1->TextChanged` - это событие, обработка которого, судя по Вашему коду, делегируется методу `textBox1_TextChanged`. Скорее всего, Вам интересно значение свойства `textBox1->Text`, которое меет тип `string`. А чтобы из строки получить целое число, нужно воспользоваться одним из перегруженных статических методов `Parse` у типа `System::Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

`System::Int32::Parse`